# Python - How to get Instagram media id

Tags: python, media, instagram-api

In order do get Instagram data for some queries, I have checked [Instagram API for media](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search), and a tutorial [here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram)

But the tutorial does't work for me.

When I tried `media_search()`, it always returns empty list. When I tried `media_popular()`, it seems that this method and other media methods need `media_id`. However, I didn't find anyway to get a list of media_id through a certain query. Therefore, I thought whether `media_search()` could return the media_id, but it's empty.

Here is my code:

```
# Generate Instagram API
Instagram_api = InstagramAPI(access_token=Instagram_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                  client_id=Instagram_CLIENT_ID,
                  client_secret=Instagram_CLIENT_SECRET)

# try media_search method
media_search = Instagram_api.media_search(q="food", count=10, lat=47.6038321, lng=-122.3300623, distance=5000)
```

print media_search

Is there any way could get a list of media_id for a certain query, through Python?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Media id is the id of a specific Instagram post/photo. You should be able to call `Instagram_api.media_popular(count=10)` for instance, no need for media id unless you're querying for a specific post (like with `Instagram_api.media()` and related).

Comment: I tried this, it always show "InstagramAPIError: (400) APINotFoundError-invalid media id". Therefore I assume it needs media id~